# how to filter nested dictionaries of a json file, in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, database-design, filtering, one-to-many

I have a JSON file with data which looks like this:

Sample data: (actual data would have years of exchange rates)

Original:

```
{
   "rates":{
      "2018-01-22":{
         "BGN":1.9558,
         "TRY":4.6552,
         "CNY":7.8374,
         "NOK":9.6223,
         "NZD":1.6758
      },
      "2018-01-09":{
         "BGN":1.9558,
         "TRY":4.4843,
         "CNY":7.7865,
         "NOK":9.6715,
         "NZD":1.6601
      }
   },
   "start_at":"2018-01-01",
   "base":"EUR",
   "end_at":"2018-02-01"
}
```

Expected:

```
{
   "rates":{
      "2018-01-22":{
         "BGN":1.9558,
         "CNY":7.8374,
         "NZD":1.6758
      },
      "2018-01-09":{
         "BGN":1.9558,
         "CNY":7.7865,
         "NZD":1.6601
      }
   },
   "start_at":"2018-01-01",
   "base":"EUR",
   "end_at":"2018-02-01"
}
```

Mainly I need help in:

1. How can I select only the currencies that I need? Like only 'BGN' ,'CNY' and 'NZD'. I am using Pyhton.

Would be really helpful to get some advice on this too:

2. After filtering out the currencies I need to create Two tables over this data in mysql, with one table consisting of all currency and other historical rates. with one-to-many relation. Which would be correct database structure to store from above mentioned dict structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve it by a list/dict comprehension. But there is more than one way of doing it. Here is an example of a list/dict comprehension. In the variable choice you put all your currencies you want to stay:

```
data = {'rates': {'2018-01-22': {'BGN': 1.9558, 'TRY': 4.6552, 
'CNY': 7.8374, 'NOK': 9.6223, 'NZD': 1.6758}, '2018-01-09': 
{'BGN': 1.9558, 'TRY': 4.4843, 'CNY': 7.7865, 'NOK': 9.6715, 
'NZD': 1.6601}}, 'start_at': '2018-01-01', 'base': 'EUR', 
'end_at': '2018-02-01'}

choice = ("BGN", "CNY", "NZD")

filtered = {date: {x: data.get("rates").get(date).get(x) for x in data.get("rates").get(date) if x in choice} for date in data.get("rates")}

data["rates"] = filtered

print(data)
```

Regarding the DB:
I would probably go for columns like the following. But this also depends on how the data is used.

**date** | **currency1** | ... | **currencyN** | **base**

Then you can easly sort and filter by date or a currency, which is most likely what you want most of the time.

Comment: instead of single table, if i wish to have 2 tables, one for currency and another for historical data, which common column(to join) would you suggest?

Comment: What do you mean by historical data? What shall be the purpose of table1 and of table2? If you only want to compare with historical data later on it makes sense to build both tables up in the same order

Comment: Anyway, you may want to ask another separated question regarding the DB structure because this is a whole new topic. If my answer helps you with your problem please mark is as accepted, thanks.